# Is it possible to set different autoplay timeout for owl carousel items?

Tags: owl-carousel

I have a carousel slider which includes photos and video as items. So, is it possible to set *autoplayTimeout:5000* for image items and *autoplayTimeout:25000* for video items?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

to solve this problem i used this approach:

- when activating the owl first time, give the time you'd like for the first image (eg. 6s in my case)

  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                  autoplay: true,
                  autoplayTimeout: 6000,
                  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
                  lazyload: true,
                  nav: false,
                  items: 1
              });
- then, on the first 'change' event (not changeD, just change that is the exact change moment) you check that is the first change. If the case, you stop and restart the owl triggering the new interval from now onwards, eg 3s in my case:

  $('.owl-carousel').on('change.owl.carousel', function (e) {
                      //console.log(e);
                      if (e.namespace && e.property.name === 'position'
                      && (e.relatedTarget.relative(e.property.value) == 1)
                      ) {
                          $('.owl-carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                          setTimeout(
                          function () {
                              $('.owl-carousel').trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [3000]); //from now on we go to 3s
                          }, 0);
                      }
                  });

now, put the video for the first element and you're done!

Comment: can you tell me if video item was on 2nd item. what can we do?

Answer (score 0):

yes,in my case i was having video on my owl carousel and i wanted to keep the video time as 10 seconds and rest as 5 seconds and i did this customization.

```
$("#carousel").owlCarousel({
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 5000,
smartSpeed: 800,
nav: false,
items: 1,
onInitialized: function(e) { 
  var $activeItem = $("#carousel").find('.owl-item.active');
  var videItem  = $activeItem.find('video');
  if(videItem.length >0){
    $('#carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    setTimeout(function () { 
    $("#carousel").trigger('play.owl.autoplay')}, 10000)
  }
},
onTranslated: function(e){
  var $activeItem = $("#carousel").find('.owl-item.active');
  var videItem  = $activeItem.find('video');
  if(videItem.length >0){
    $('#carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    setTimeout(function () { 
    $("#carousel").trigger('play.owl.autoplay')}, 10000)
  }
 }
});
```

on every translate/change to the item it will check whether the current active item is having video element or not.

same we can extend for position of each item by using this code

```
onTranslated: function(e){
  var activeItemIndex = e.item.index;
  if(activeItemIndex == 2){
    $('#carousel').trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    setTimeout(function () { 
    $("#carousel").trigger('play.owl.autoplay')}, 10000)
  }
 }
```